# Can I run Node.JS with low privileges?

Tags: node.js

I would like to run node with a low privileges user, is it possible? I need to use the framework Express.js

Comment: Define "low privileges user."

Comment: I don't want to tun node.js with ROOT privileges.

Comment: What makes you think you have to? I've never needed to do so.

Comment: You only need root access to run node on port 80.

Comment: @pono: all port under 1024 need root access

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. There are many solutions available to do this, depending on your exact needs.

If you want to run node on port 80, you can use nginx (doesn't work with WebSockets yet) or [haproxy](http://cloud.ubuntu.com/2011/09/node-js-and-mongodb-on-ubuntu/). But perhaps the quickest and dirtiest is to use iptables to redirect port 80 to the port of your choice:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8003
sudo iptables -t nat -L
```

When you’re happy, then save the config and make sure iptables comes on at boot

```
sudo service iptables save
sudo chkconfig iptables on
```

To automatically start your nodejs service as non-root, and restart it if it fails, you can utilize [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) with a script like this:

```
#!upstart
description "nodeapp"
author      "you"

start on started mountall
stop on shutdown

# Automatically Respawn:
respawn
respawn limit 99 5

script
   export HOME="/home/user/"
   exec sudo -u user /usr/local/bin/node /home/user/app.js 2>&1 >> /home/user/app.log
end script
```

If you're on an Amazon EC2 installation, or you get an error that says `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`, then you can replace your exec command with this:

```
#!upstart
description "nodeapp"
author      "you"

start on started mountall
stop on shutdown

# Automatically Respawn:
respawn
respawn limit 99 5

script
   export HOME="/home/user/"
   #amazon EC2 doesn’t allow sudo from script! so use su --session-command
   exec su --session-command="/usr/local/bin/node /home/user/app.js 2>&1 >> /home/user/app.log" user &
end script
```

And, you didn't ask this question, but to keep it running forever, check out monit! Here is [a useful guide to setting up node.js with upstart and monit](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://howtonode.org/deploying-node-upstart-monit&ei=KMfVTsnqGIqjiQLDlKnFCg&usg=AFQjCNHxmyhR89qh4C1gtI55sci69Jlvcw).

Comment: What does setting HOME actually do here?

Comment: Depending on the specific version of node you are using, what your directory structure looks like, and whether node was installed by root or the current user, the answer varies between everything and nothing :) It may tell node where it's going to be run from, it may be completely ignored (note that I incorrectly put `/home/user/nodeapp` in my example, when it should match the app.js location of `/home/user/`, i.e. where require() is going to look for modules)

Comment: On EC2 my Ubuntu (12.04) didn't have a `--session-command` switch for `su`. I ran `exec su - $USER -c '/usr/bin/node /path/to/node/app.js 2>&1 >> /path/to/node/app.log'`

Comment: That's another option and a great choice; I'm surprised you'd need even that for Ubuntu